# Unix while loop to test command line argument if it is a directory

Tags: shell, unix

Trying to make a script that will take a command line argument as a pathname and then test if it is a working directory. Then I wish to run commands (tests) on the directory such as how many files in what sub directories etc.

I am unable to think of a logic to test this with. How would you determine if the argument is a directory?

This is what I have tried

```
if [ -d "$1" ]
then
    echo "It works"
fi
```

I dont get "It works" when I try this. So I switched it to -a for a file because it is easier to test. And again, I do not get the echo output.

Comment: What does "test if it is a working directory" mean?  Test whether it is the working directory of the current process?  Test whether it is a checkout from some version control system?  Test whether it is a directory the user has access to?

Comment: Your code works when you pass it a directory.  How exactly did you test it? http://pastebin.com/jYTpArFp

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-d` option to the [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html) command.

```
if [ -d "$1" ]
then ...
fi
```

Comment: Does $pathname refer to the argument passed when running the script? The user should be able to just type script1 /home/apple and then it will check?

Comment: You can do `pathname=$1` to get the argument. I thought your question was about how to test for a directory, and assumed you knew how to access arguments in general.

Comment: Well I was thinking I could just do if [ -d "$1" ] since a pathname doesn't have spaces?

Comment: You can do that even if the pathname does have spaces, the quotes deal with that.

Comment: Ok I have tested this using -a and trying with a file. But for the commands to run I have just a simple echo "it works". It isn't executing the echo statement which means it isn't saying the file exists but the file does exist.

Comment: This tests whether the name exists and is a directory. If it's an ordinary file it won't run the commands.

Comment: Yes -a tests if the file exists. Which is what I was trying because i wanted to make sure I could get something running first. I have updated the orignal post to show you what I have tried. I have the code right, atleast I think. But the echo is not printing.

Comment: `-e` tests if the file exists, not `-a`.

Comment: Hm, my book is wrong then. Has nothing in it for -e and it didn't work either.

Comment: What book are you reading? Are you sure it's talking about shell scripting? Does its description look anything like the man page I linked to?

Comment: `-a` is the `AND` operator in `test`, I don't know why your book would say it has anything to do with file testing.

Comment: Unix The Complete Reference, Second Edition by Kenneth Rosenet. Also no it just has a chart of what each file test does.

Comment: Ahh, sounds like you're looking at the description of the bash `[[` operator. It's a little different from the traditional `test` command, because it's built-in shell syntax rather than a command, and it uses both `-a` and `-e` to test if a file exists.

Comment: Hmm weird because it says..... You can also evaluate the status of files and directories in your if statements. For example, if [ -a "$1" ] checks to see if the first argument to the script is a valid filename.

Comment: It turns out that `bash` extends the regular `[` command, too. But the standard operator is `-e`.

Comment: Make sure your script begins with `#!/bin/bash` if you want to make use of bash extensions.

Comment: Ah ok, will do that. Just trying to complete an assignment since I am new to unix. Returning home from a deployment tomorrow and want to have it done before weekend. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The title mentions a while loop, but none of the previous commentary seems to mention that.  You might try a simple script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg; do
  if test -d "$arg";
    echo "$arg is a directory"
  else
    echo "$arg is not a directory"
  fi
done
```

For variety, you could rewrite that as:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg; do
  not=$(test -d "$arg" || echo "NOT ")
  echo "$arg is ${not}a directory"
done
```